# VBA Coding: What does .ListObjects actually do?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to alter some code for a post-processing of data excel template.

The previous code is using arrays which I will admit I am new to, I have tried to work out what

```
.ListObjects
```

does?

Here is the code that I am currently sulking over...

```
Sub DefineLists()

Dim sheetArr(1 to 5) as Worksheet
Dim tblArr(1 to 5) as ListObject


'set array of sheet names
Set sheetArr(1) = Sheets("All Data")
Set sheetArr(2) = Sheets("Day")
Set sheetArr(3) = Sheets("Evening")
Set sheetArr(4) = Sheets("Night")
Set sheetArr(5) = Sheets("Weekend")

'set array of table names
Set tblArr(1) = sheetArr(1).ListObjects("tblAllData")
Set tblArr(2) = sheetArr(2).ListObjects("tblDayData")
Set tblArr(3) = sheetArr(3).ListObjects("tblEveData")
Set tblArr(4) = sheetArr(4).ListObjects("tblNightData")
Set tblArr(5) = sheetArr(5).ListObjects("tblWeekendData")

End Sub
```

I am just desperately trying to work out what the second set of "set" statements are doing!

The sheets also have some rather complex formulas (=blahblahblah) written in the cells, so is the .ListObjects creating an array where it stores all of those formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ListObjects: A Collection of ListObjects
>
> ListObject: A table on a worksheet

A Slice of your code

> sheetArr(1): Sheets("All Data")
>
> .ListObjects("tblAllData"): A refernce to a ListObject named tblAllData
>
> sheetArr(1).ListObjects("tblAllData"): Refers to a table named "tblAllData: on the Worksheet names "All Data"

Answer (score 1):

`ListObjects` is the collection of `ListObject`s on a sheet [(Documentation here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197604.aspx)  Basically, this set of `Set` calls is assigning the Table array index positions to the specific `ListObject`s referenced by those names on the sheet.  (FYI, that array is not a list of table names, but a list of the actual Table `ListObject`s themselves)

Comment: note the "s" following some of the `ListObject` tags is intentional, as there is a distinction between `ListObjects` and `ListObject`

Comment: thankyou for your quick reply! I see, now can i be even more dumb and ask what makes an object an object? is it any variable that you set?

Comment: @lewisthegruffalo this is a general coding concept rather than something specific to VBA.  Can't exactly give you an adequate crash course through a comment here, but googling about the concept of Objects and Types in VBA should give you some good information about that

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @RGA

Comment: @lewisthegruffalo if you believe this answer (or any other) solves your problem, please mark it as "answered" with the check to remove this question from the unanswered question queue

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an array of individual [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) objects with `Dim tblArr(1 to 5) as ListObject` (note singlular form of ListObject).

Later you are setting each element of the array to a particular ListObject from the [ListObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174246.aspx) collection (note plural form). This is all of the ListObjects on the worksheet identified by the previously set `sheetArr` element. The individual object is identified from the ListObjects collection by the table name ; e.g. `tblAllData` or `tblDayData`.